# einsum equivalent for ndarray multiplication

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-einsum

I have the following multiplication routine:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(3,3)
b = np.random.rand(3,50,50)
res = np.zeros((3, 50, 50))
for i in range(50):
    for j in range(50):
        res[:,i,j] = a @ b[:,i,j]
```

What is the `einsum` equivalent expression?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to brush up on [Einstein summation notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation):

```
res = np.einsum('ij, jkl -> ikl', a, b)
```

In this case, `np.tensordot` is also useful:

```
np.tensordot(a ,b, 1).shape
Out[]: (3, 50, 50)
```